# Create an LVM snaphot targeting another volume group possible?

Tags: lvm

I want to backup LVM volumes to another volume group. Is this possible?

> sudo lvcreate -s /dev/$VG/$LV -n $SNAP_NAME $VS 2>>$LOG

Comment: Snapshots are not backups, it is just means of having consistent filesystem. Create a snapshot in same VG, then backup the snapshot (whole LV using dd or rsync the filesystem) to another VG. If you have only snapshot it is not a backup anyway.

Answer (score 2):

In short: no, you can't. Snapshots must reside on the same volume group as the original volume. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28942795/lvm-create-snapshot-between-volume-groups) and [here](https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-lvm/2008-April/msg00037.html) for more details.